# check for available updates for apps/software on my mac through command line script

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I want to write a command line script that check for available updates for all the applications on my mac and install the updates if  they are available. Anyone have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

use the:

```
softwareupdate -h   #for help
```

or

```
softwareupdate -l   #for list
```

or

```
sudo softwareupdate -iva   #install
```